# Hide parent div if text string length is more than 3 characters in a php while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a php loop that outputs a box with a form in it. At the moment if you click on the button or change one of the select boxes then the top layer is hidden and it shows another layer with a rest button on it. I want it to automatically hide the top layer if the 'todo' div has a text string longer than 3. I have tried to program this using similar programming to when the buttons are clicked/options selected. Can anybody see what is wrong with my programming? Below is the code I have used for todo.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($(".todo").text().length > 3) {
 $(this).parentsUntil(".submitted").addClass("hidediv");
    $(this).parentsUntil(".submitted").removeClass("showdiv");
}
});
</script>
```

Here is the full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<?php include 'dbconnection.php'; ?>


<link href="hidphptest.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".cars").change(function(){
   $(this).parentsUntil(".submitted").addClass("hidediv");
    $(this).parentsUntil(".submitted").removeClass("showdiv");
});
});



</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".go45").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings().addClass("showdiv");
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("hidediv");

});
});


</script>



<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$(".go1").click(function()
{$(this).parent().addClass("hidediv"); 
$(this).parent().removeClass("showdiv");   });});



</script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($(".todo").text().length > 3) {
 $(this).parentsUntil(".submitted").addClass("hidediv");
    $(this).parentsUntil(".submitted").removeClass("showdiv");
}
});
</script>


<body>

</br>


<form  method="post" action="testplace2.php">
<select name="classu" >
<option  disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Class</option>
    <?php
$selectclass=$connect->query("SELECT DISTINCT class FROM `firstnametest` ");
 while($rows=$selectclass->fetch_array())
{
 ?>
<option value="<?php echo $rows['class']; ?>"><?php echo $rows['class']; ?>
 </option>
<?php
}
?>



<input type="submit" value="Add Group" style="width: 317px; height: 45px"/>
</form> 

 </select>

 <?php
include 'dbconnection.php';
$groupder = $_POST['classu'];

?>
<h1><?php echo $groupder ?></h1></br>

<?php




$query=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * from firstnametest where class = 
'$groupder'" );
// Initiate a counter variable
$i = 1;
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
?>






 <div class="submitted ">
<button id="butest<?= $i ?>" type="button"   class="go45 btn btn-info " 
 value="<?php  echo$row["id"];   ?>">Go Back</button>
<div class="todo "></br><?php  echo$row["surname"];   ?></br>

<button type="button" onclick="return buter('<?= $i ?>')"  class="go1 btn 
btn-info " value="<?php  echo$row["id"];   ?>">Button test</button> 


<select  class="cars" >
<option  disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Group </option>
<option value="Group 1">Group 1</option>
<option value="Group 2">Group 2</option>
<option value="Group 3">Group 3</option>
<option value="Group 4">Group 4</option>
</select>



<select onchange="return chka('<?= $i ?>')" id="names<?= $i ?>" class="cars 
changetest" >
<option  disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Activity</option>
    <?php
$classdrop=$connect->query("SELECT * from clubs ");
while($rows=$classdrop->fetch_array())
{
?>
<option class="changetest" value="<?php echo $rows['Club']; ?>"><?php echo 
 $rows['Club']; ?></option>
 <?php
 }
?>

</select>
<br/>  
<div >

</div> 
</div>
</div>
<?php
// Increment the counter
$i++;
}

?>




</body>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

**Q: Can anybody see what is wrong with my programming?** 

**Answer:** 
first thing that you should do before you debug is to fix you html document and follow the correct guidelines of calling external scripts. I also notice that you are implementing a bad habit of executing sql queries inside of your display page which is actually a common mistake that developers should avoid.

1. Include files such as dbcon are always located at the beginning of the code. 
   `include 'dbconnection.php'`
2. There is also a standard structure of html document.

example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

3. Most of the time, Javascripts which is embedded internally are located at the bottom part of the html document if it is not from external js file.